# Lagging recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have made a recyclerView which is inside a fragment. It has an ImageView in each item and the image is loaded with Picasso from a url. But the problem is that the recyclerView lags when i scroll for the first time, but when the data is loaded, it scrolls normally. I tried to remove all the operations in the onBindViewHolder but the problem still persists. I then removed the complex part of the item layout but still no improvements. I am running on Snapdragon 845 so there is no issue with the phone's performance, I tried the same with other devices and it lags. I even tried with hardware acceleration, but it didn't help.

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieHolder> {

    private List<Movie> mMovies;
    private Context mContext;

    public MovieAdapter(Context mContext, List<Movie> mMovies) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mMovies = mMovies;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MovieHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view =  LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_movie_movie_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new MovieHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieHolder movieHolder, int i) {
        Movie movie = mMovies.get(i);

        if (movie.getTitle2().equals("")) {
            movieHolder.mTextViewTitle1.setText(movie.getTitle1());
            movieHolder.mTextViewTitle2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            movieHolder.mTextViewTitle1.setText(movie.getTitle1());
            movieHolder.mTextViewTitle2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            movieHolder.mTextViewTitle2.setText(movie.getTitle2());
        }

        movieHolder.mTextViewGenre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        movieHolder.mRatingBar.setRating((float) 4.5);
        String url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342";
        url += movie.getPoster_path();

        Transformation transformation = new Rounded(8, ALL);

        Picasso.get().load(url)
                .placeholder(R.color.colorAccent)
                .transform(transformation)
                .resize(100, 150)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(movieHolder.mImageViewPoster);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMovies.size();
    }

    public class MovieHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements     View.OnClickListener {
        private ImageView mImageViewPoster;
        private TextView mTextViewTitle1;
        private TextView mTextViewTitle2;
        private TextView mTextViewGenre;
        private RatingBar mRatingBar;

        public MovieHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mImageViewPoster = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_poster);
            mTextViewTitle1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title_1);
            mTextViewTitle2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title_2);
            mTextViewGenre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_genre);
            mRatingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Movie movie = mMovies.get(getAdapterPosition());
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA", movie);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my item layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_poster"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_view_poster"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Skyscraper"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Skyscraper"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:outlineProvider="paddedBounds"
                android:progressBackgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
                android:progressTint="#FECE00"
                android:stepSize="0.5" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_genre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="Action | Adventure"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I never used this library but I suggest to do the ´transform´ after ´resize´ (to be sure it is done on the scaled image and not on the source-image).

Comment: Yes worked absolutely fine!